# npm run storybook throwing ugy error as `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'string')` in browser

Tags: reactjs, react-native, storybook

I am trying to set up storybook for an existing react native application, for which I have followed the official docs.
Now, when I try running npm run storybook, I am getting the following error in browser:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVfx8.png)

in the emulator, the stories are also not reflecting in the sidebar.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ek8qU.png)

index.js

```
import {getStorybookUI,configure} from '@storybook/react-native';
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import { loadStories } from './storyLoader';
// configure(loadStories, module);

const StorybookUIRoot = getStorybookUI({
    // onDeviceUI:true,
    // resetStorybook:true
});
AppRegistry.registerComponent('cdcapp', () => StorybookUIRoot);

export default StorybookUIRoot;
```

main.js

```
module.exports = {
  stories: ['./*.stories.?(ts|tsx|js|jsx)'],
  addons: ['@storybook/addon-ondevice-controls', '@storybook/addon-ondevice-actions'],
  framework: "@storybook/react",
};
```

Kindly help out, any leads are helpful.

I tried everything according to the official docs and was expecting it to run smoothly.

Comment: can you provide more details about your setup? however it looks like you are missing the storbyook.require.js file